# Simple delete query using EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework, delete-row

Is there any way to accomplsig something simple as this using EF Code First

```
DELETE FROM Order WHERE OrderDate >= @minOrderDate AND OrderDate >= @maxOrderDate
```

I have a table of which I would like to delete at least 10.000 records. I think it would be rather inefficient to retrieve all records first before I can delete them using a for-each loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always send across raw SQL through your context.  `_context.Database.SqlQuery(sqlDeleteStatement, parameterList)`

```
string sqlDeleteStatement = "DELETE FROM Order" + 
    "WHERE OrderDate >= @minOrderDate AND OrderDate >= @maxOrderDate";

List<SqlParameter> parameterList = new List<SqlParameter>();

parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@minOrderDate", minDate));

parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@maxOrderDate", maxDate));

_context.Database.SqlQuery(sqlDeleteStatement, parameterList);
```

Comment: I saw this option comming up in intellisense but wondered if writing SQL code was the only way to go to make this simple db operation work

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the code provided here does not even compile - both the [generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545(v=vs.103).aspx) and [non-generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679117(v=vs.103).aspx) versions of `SqlQuery` take a type argument, either as a generic or a regular method argument. Did you mean to use [`ExecuteSqlStatement` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679456(v=vs.103).aspx)?

Comment: This is not an answer at all. -1.

Answer (score 31):

You can use

```
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlDeleteStatement,
    new SqlParameter("@minOrderDate", minDate),
    new SqlParameter("@maxOrderDate", maxDate));
```

*NOTE: The accepted answer does not compile.*